# How do I add bold, smallcap font?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I've got this:

```
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Equity_Text_B_Regular.otf}[
        BoldFont          = Equity_Text_B_Bold.otf ,
        ItalicFont        = Equity_Text_B_Italic.otf ,
        BoldItalicFont    = Equity_Text_B_Bold_Italic.otf , 
        SmallCapsFont     = Equity_Caps_B_Regular.otf ]
```

And I have another font file in my project directory called Equity_Caps_B_Bold.otf. I want the following text to print in bold, smallcaps, but it is printing in regular, smallcaps:

```
    \centerline{\bf{\textsc {\CourtNameOne}}}
```

What's the best practice for adding bold, smallcaps when my font family has a specific file for that? I'm using the LuaTeX engine.

Comment: Welcome! `\bf` is 20+ years obsolete and ought not be used in LaTeX. `\centerline` is also usually wrong, as I understand it. The `fontspec` manual explains how to do what you need.

Comment: Note that if you had the fonts installed, you wouldn't need to specify the individual font files this way. (Probably.)

Comment: Instead of `\bf{\textsc {\CourtNameOne}`, you should definitely write `\textbf{\textsc{\CourtNameOne}}`. Your main challenge will be to inform `fontspec` how to access the bold-smallcaps font combination. (I'm afraid I can't give any advice on that since I don't have access to any of the `Equity_...` fonts.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EquityTextB}[
BoldFont          = *-Bold,
ItalicFont        = *-Italic,
BoldItalicFont    = *-BoldItalic, 
SmallCapsFont     = EquityCapsB,
BoldFeatures      = {SmallCapsFont=EquityCapsB-Bold}
]    
\begin{document}

\textsc {CourtNameOne}
\textbf{\textsc {CourtNameOne}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This definition should also work, `fontspec` will find all fonts:

```
\setmainfont{EquityTextB}[
  SmallCapsFont = EquityCapsB,
  BoldFeatures  = {SmallCapsFont=EquityCapsB-Bold}
]
```